# jQuery datetimepicker- unable to select date from next year

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, datetimepicker

I am working on a Python/ Django project, and one of the forms on a webpage has a `datetimepicker` field on which the user can select a date/ time from the drop-down that appears when the field is selected.

The problem that I currently have is that although the calendar displays a full month at a time, and the user can move through months/ years at a time by selecting next/ previous month, or choosing the year from a drop down inside the calendar, if they move to a month beyond the end of this year, then none of the dates are available for selection.

Having Google'd `datetimepicker`, it seems that this is a jQuery function, and I want to make sure that there is no value for its `maxDate` attribute- I've looked through `jquery.datetimepicker.full.js`, and although it's referenced there, it doesn't see to be given a value at all... so I can't see why this field is not allowing me to select a date beyond the end of this year... anyone have any ideas?

The `view` that is rendering this page is:

```
def concept(request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.prefetch_related('budget_versions').get(id=project_id)
    deposit = Deposit.objects.get_or_create(project=project)[0]
    presentations = project.budget_versions.select_related('meeting').prefetch_related('budget_items', 'cci_items', 'presenters').filter(version_number__isnull=False).annotate(vn=F('version_number') * -1).order_by('presentation_date', 'created', '-vn')
    end_details = EndDetails.objects.get_or_create(project=project)[0]
    presentation_formset = BudgetPresentationFormset(prefix="presentations", instance=project, queryset=presentations)
    drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))

    context = {
        'project': project,
        'presentations': presentations,
        'presentation_formset': presentation_formset,
        'drawing_formset': drawing_formset,
        'deposit_form': DepositInfoForm(instance=deposit),
        'ended_form': EndDetailsForm(instance=end_details),
        'budget_notes_form': BudgetNotesForm(instance=project.budget_overview),
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/concept.html', context)
```

and the Django that is displaying the form on which the 'date' field is displayed is:

```
{% if not forloop.last and presentation_form.instance.budget_items.count %}
    <tr class="split-rows">
        <td colspan="3">Exc VAT {% if not presentation_form.instance.current_marker %}{{presentation_form.instance.grand_total_exc_vat|money:'£'}}{% else %}{{project.budget_overview.updated_exc_vat|money:'£'}}{% endif %}</td>
        <td colspan="3">Inc VAT {% if not presentation_form.instance.current_marker %}{{presentation_form.instance.grand_total_inc_vat|money:'£'}}{% else %}{{project.budget_overview.updated_inc_vat|money:'£'}}{% endif %}</td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
    <tr>
        {% for hidden in presentation_form.hidden_fields %}
            <td class="hidden">{{ hidden }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for field in presentation_form.visible_fields %}
        <tr class="split-rows">
            {% if not field.name == 'pdf_package_dep' %}
                <td colspan="6"><label>{{field.label}}</label></td>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>

        <tr class="split-rows">

            <td colspan="6">
                {% if not field.name == 'pdf_package_dep' %}
                    {% if field.name == 'presentation_date' %}
                        {% with presentation_form.instance.meeting as meeting %}
                            {% include "projects/includes/meeting_bit.html" with employee=request.user.employee meeting=meeting UID=presentation_form.instance.id %}
                        {% endwith %}
                        {# <a class="ical_trigger button" data-view-url="{% url 'events:add_to_cal' %}" {% if not field.value %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>Add to calendar</a> #}
                    {% else %}
                        {{field}}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

**Edit**

It would appear that what's actually displaying the calendar is the HTML file included by the line:

```
{% include "projects/includes/meeting_bit.html" with employee=request.user.employee meeting=meeting UID=presentation_form.instance.id %}
```

The `meeting_bit.html` file has the following code:

```
{% if meeting and meeting.event_creator and meeting.event_creator != employee %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{meeting.date|date:"d/m/Y H:i"}}<br>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2"><a class="change_event_organiser" data-view-url="{% url 'events:change_event_creator' meeting.id %}" class="button">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-sm">
                Organised by {{meeting.event_creator}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{% else %}

    <div id="cal_{{field.name}}_{{UID}}">
        {{field}}
        <a class="ical_trigger button" data-view-url="{% url 'events:add_to_cal' %}" {% if not field.value %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>
        {% if meeting.event_id %}Update calendar event{% else %}Add to calendar{% endif %}
        </a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I can see when I 'inspect' the date field of the form in the browser, that it is in a `div` which has an ID in the format `cal_{{field.name}}_{{UID}}`, so I know that this is where the calendar is initialised/ displayed... But I can't see anything that is restricting the available options for selection to dates from this year only... why can't I select a date from next year, or any other year in the future?

Comment: Did you try this widget from JQuery UI : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: i think jQuery UI plugin is best for "datetimepicker"   Have a look on this link---> https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: I haven't tried the widget- I've only recently taken on the development/ maintenance of this software... it appears that this is already using a jQuery `datetimepicker`- when I inspect the form field that displays the date in the browser, the browser console shows the `<div>` tag, with an `<input class="datetimepicker presentation_date" ....>` tag inside, however, that is not shown in the HTML template for this page- the HTML from this template is shown in my OP.